# $ is not defined on my javascript with multiple function and ajax inside each function

Tags: javascript

Im am using Microsoft Edge in the scenario.

I as able to successfully do a single function with a ajax syntax with this code:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("inputEventID").onchange = function () { myFunction() };

    function myFunction() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'webFetchMax.php',
        data: {
            eventID: form.eventID.value
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#divSlots').html(response);
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

However when I insert addition functions with their on ajax inside the function I am receiving *$ is not defined* error *function monitorOccupy()* as shown below:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("inputEventID").onchange = function () { myFunction() };

    monitorOccupy();
    monitorAvail();
    function monitorOccupy() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'webFetchMax.php',
        data: {
            eventID: form.eventID.value
        },
        success: function (response) { 
            $('#oSlots').html(response);
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(monitorOccupy,1000);
        }
    });
    }
    function monitorAvail() {
    }

    function myFunction() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'webFetchMax.php',
        data: {
            eventID: form.eventID.value
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#divSlots').html(response);
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

I have no idea my is this error is showing up on my console.

Comment: Please make sure that jQuery is the fist script in order from top to bottom, and that it's not `defer` or `async`

Answer (score -2):

Call these functions as below

> $(document).ready(function(){
>        monitorOccupy();
>        MonitorAvail();
>    });

Answer (score -2):

Before posting this question the only jQuery file in my html file was *jquery.min.js*

```
<script scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After inserting another *jquery.min.js* file my problem is solved. This is what it looks now:

```
<script scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Those two files are essentially the same thing minus a minor build number/changes. You should not have both. Either version 3.2.0 has some unknown bug or you have another issue. This fix only serves to mask the real issue.

Comment: I was thinking that but whatever the case is it technically it fix my problem. My scripts are working properly now.

Comment: You wont get very far as a programmer if you dont understand the issues you are resolving.

Comment: Good point. I will try to understand more in the future but now I have a project to be submitted soon, this solution will do for now. Thank you!